# Django Admin Unicode in URLField

Tags: django, unicode, admin

I have a model called City and in that model I have a URLField. Using the Django Admin tool I am trying to enter this url "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Düsseldorf". The Admin complains this is an invalid url probably because of the "ü" unicode character. In the documentation
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#urlfield you can read the following statement: "Changed in Django 1.2: The URLField previously did not recognize URLs as valid that contained an IDN (Internationalized Domain Name; a domain name containing unicode characters) domain name. This has now been corrected. But I am getting an error message: "Enter a Valid URL". I am using Django version 1.2.2.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Just a note "IDN", applies to the domain name portion of the URL only (de.wikipedia.org) and not the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Düsseldorf
```

Isn't a URI, it's an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier).

If your software doesn't support IRIs directly, you will have to convert it manually yourself. Apart from the hostname part, which indeed uses IDN encoding, this means using UTF-8 and URL-encoding:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%BCsseldorf

This will typically still display as ‘Düsseldorf’ in modern, IRI-supporting web browsers (follow the link to see).